# Cordova showing shows default splash screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen

I working on a small app for iOS, I replace all the images inside platforms/ios/app/resources/splash with my own images, but it still showing the default image, any ideas why is doing this?

Comment: Have you run `cordova prepare ios` and/or are launching the app from xcode?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Im launching the app from xcode

Comment: I've had this issue before, it appears that xcode is caching the images. I have solved this by manually reselecting the images in xcode (even though they have the same name) and then launching the app again. Additionally, I believe running `cordova prepare ios` will also work.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon im running cordova built iOS, cordova prepare iOS and looking in xcode I see my images and im trying to reselect but I don't know how because is not working

Comment: In xcode, click on your base project in the explorer tab, then make sure the app selected under 'targets' and in the 'general' tab scroll down to 'launch images'. Next to each image click the folder icon and select the correct image. This should resolve the issue the next time the app is launched.

Comment: Great! I will add this as an answer for anyone else who finds this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here another option you can use

1. - Command-Option-Shift-K to clean out the build folder.
2. - Quit Xcode and using the terminal clean ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData manually. Remove all its contents because there's a bug where Xcode will run an old version of your project that's in there somewhere.
3. - go the terminal open the app, run, cordova build ios, cordova prepare ios

Answer (score 1):

If you run `cordova build` or `cordova prepare` before you have placed your splashscreen images they will become cached by xcode. To resolve this follow these steps:

In xcode -

- Click on your base project in the Explorer window
- Make sure your app is selected under the `Targets` heading
- Selected the `General` tab
- Scroll down to the `Launch Images` section
- Click the folder icon next to each image and select the appropriate file for each
- Re-launch your app